# «Trovejar» ou «trovoar»?

Tags: significado, ortografia, diferenças

Deve dizer-se «trovejar» ou «trovoar»?

Exemplo:

> Ontem as 22 horas estava a _______ muito.

Answer (score 3):

Ambas as respostas estão corretas. Segundo o dicionário Aurélio:

> Significado de **Trovejar**
>
> 1 - O ruído da trovoada.
>
> 2 - Grande estrondo.
>
> 3 - Fulminar com.
>
> 4 - Haver trovoada; soar (o trovão).
>
> 5 - Retumbar; ribombar.
>
> 6 - Bradar; clamar.
>
> 7 - Repreender com voz troante.
>
> Significado de **Trovoar**
>
> 1 - Trovejar.

Porém, segundo o site Ciber Dúvidas, trovejar é mais culto e trovoar é mais de uso popular:

> Ambas as palavras estão correctas. No entanto, trovejar é palavra mais
>   culta; trovoar, de uso mais popular. Observe-se que, estilisticamente,
>   trovejar, como a maior parte dos verbos terminados em ejar, tem
>   sentido mais dinâmico do que trovoar. Camilo tê-la-ia preferido. A
>   propósito, acrescente-se o que José Pedro Machado escreve no seu
>   "Grande Dicionário da Língua Portuguesa", Algés, 1989, vol. XII, p.
>   274, para a forma trovejar: «No sentido próprio é verbo defectivo
>   impessoal, pois se conjuga apenas na 3ª pessoa do singular; em muitos
>   casos, porém, emprega-se na 3ª do plural: os céus trovejam».

Fonte: [Ciber Dúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/trovejar-ou-trovoar/120)

Comment: Não existe isso de trovejar ser mais formal que trovoar. Use a que gostar mais. É o mesmo que dizer que entre início e começo existe uma palavra mais formal.